# How can I create a Python Script with BeautifulSoup on Windows to download the highest resolution of each picture in a WIkimedia Commons folder?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, wikimedia-commons

So, I'm a big fan of Gustave Doré, and I would like to download all his engravings from the Wikimedia Commons folders that are neatly organized.

So, **given a Wikimedia Commons folder I need to download all the pictures in it in the highest resolution**.

I started writing something, but I'm not that good, so it's just a template:

```
import os, requests, bs4

url = 'URL OF THE WIKIMEDIA COMMONS FOLDER'

os.makedirs('NAME OF THE FOLDER', exist_ok=True)
for n in range(NUMBER OF PICTURES IN THE PAGE - 1):
    print('I am downloading page number %s...' %(n+1))
    res = requests.get(url)
    res.raise_for_status()

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

    #STUFF I STILL NEED TO ADD
    
print('Done')
```

For example, I would feed this as the URL of the folder:

- https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Crusades_by_Gustave_Dor%C3%A9

Then I would like to click every link and go to the picture page, like this one:

- https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Astonishment_of_the_Crusaders_at_the_Wealth_of_the_East.jpg

And then download the '**original file**' *by clicking the link below the picture that says 'original file'*.
Except *sometimes the pic has no higher resolution available*, like in this case:

- https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Andel_krizaci.jpg

And it would just need to click the link below the picture to download it.

I am completely stuck, thanks in advance for your help!

*Bonus points if the pic has the name stated in its page when saved*

(e.g. in the second link the picture should be saved as 'Astonishment of the Crusaders at the Wealth of the East.jpg')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey big fan of Gustave Doré, here is a way you can do it

```py
r = requests.get('https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Crusades_by_Gustave_Dor%C3%A9')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
links = [i.find('img').get('src') for i in soup.find_all('a', class_='image')]
links = ['/'.join(i.split('/')[:-1]).replace('/thumb', '') for i in links]
for l in links:
    im = requests.get(l)
    with open(l.split('/')[-1], 'wb') as f:
        f.write(im.content)
```